# JQuery Chosen for state and city select list only work once

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am doing a select box for state and city. Once the user select the state,  based on the selected state, it will show the whole city list in the state. The following is the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#origin_state").chosen();

    $("#origin_state").change(function() {
        $("#origin_city").load("getCities.php?state=" + $("#dest_state").val()).prop('disabled', false);
    });

     $("#origin_city").hover(function() {

        $("#origin_city").chosen();
    }); 
});
```

I have a state and city database. getCities.php is to get the city list based on the state you choose. The problem is it only work once. Once I change state to another state, the city list dose not change, if I comment out the $("#origin_city").chosen();, it works fine. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok well your code is missing chosen plugin updating functionality, because when you apply chosen initializing function chosen() on dropdowns then they rendered as chosen dropdown and then if you want to refresh it with new data then you have to trigger chosen's custom event 'chosen:updated'. Do state-city procedure in following way.

first of all apply chosen plugin on both dropdowns by setting there class to 'chosen-select'.

```
<select id="origin_state" class="chosen-select"></select>
<select id="origin_city" class="chosen-select"></select>
```

And then your javascript code :

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen();

$('#origin_state').change(function(){
    var state = $(this).val();
    $("#origin_city").load("getCities.php?state="+state).prop('disabled',false);
    $('#origin_city').trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```